# Rails won't create new project because it thinks it's inside of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a new Rails project as I work through the book Agile Web Development with Rails.  I installed Aptana Studio 3 and created one project successfully in its default workspace.  I then decided I'd rather have it in another folder, so I deleted that one and tried to create a new one to a different path.  That's when I got the error:

> Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first. Type 'rails' for help.

I then navigated to the directory in a command prompt to confirm that it was empty.  Using "rails new TestApp" gives the same error.  I went up a level and created a new directory (to be the parent directory of the app) and received the same message there.  I was able to create multiple projects in C:\tmp, but it won't let me create any under C:\Users\Account\Development.  I have hidden files set to show, but is there something I should look for that would make rails think my Development folder is a project?

I'm in Windows 7 using ruby 1.9.3p125 and rails 3.2.3.

Comment: From what I can see, 'development' is not a reserved word in rails so that shouldn't cause a problem.  Have you tried closing the terminal and restarting it - then navigating to your development folder and running the command again?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I have restarted my computer and had the same result.

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this problem? I have the exact same problem on all my three linux systems. I have no hidden folders that would indicate a rails project in one of the parent folders. even if I create a new project at the root folder I have the same problem. This is not the case, there must be another problem here! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You have probably created a rails application is a parent folder of the folder you're trying to make one in now. I think rails looks for Gemfile (I could be wrong there) when it tries to access if the folder is a rails app. Take a look into your parent categories and search for that. Chances are you'll find the other associated pieces with it (app/, vendor/, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you [“Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please Type 'rails' for help.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176187/cant-initialize-a-new-rails-application-within-the-directory-of-another-pleas), I prefer that you search for similar kind of question over here before create a new question.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that.  The directory is completely empty and there are no .bundle files or folders present at any level that I can see (with hidden files set to visible).  I've even created new directories under .../Development to no avail.  That is why I asked if there are any other things I should be looking for.  I understand that many people probably post questions without doing research, but I did spend over an hour researching this before breaking down and posting the question.

Comment: Is there any other hidden file like `.project` or any other hidden file?(if yes then remove an try it). Finally, better you rename(recommended) or delete entire `Development` folder and create another folder with name `Development` and try to create new application under it, hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the Rails app in the parent folder. You should uninstall the application from there. Remove all the Rails files from this folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the rails app already exists on the parent directory, this error may occur. Go to the parent directory, and delete all the rails files/folders including Gemfile. Go to /Users/{your_comp_name}/ and see if you have rails files/ folders. If you do, remove those, and start your rails app again. This is kind of painful, but you may have to backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting all files and folders(~/app, ~/bin, ~/config, ~/Gemfile, ~/Gemfile.lock) generated by rails.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the rails folder from binary folder, it worked:

`cd /bin
sudo rm -rf /bin/rails`